# Google Maps API Autocompleter Custom Results

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is not a technical question, it's more a legal question.

I use the [Google Maps API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) [autocompleter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete), with injected custom results.
The custom results are styled different from the Google API results.

- Is it allowed, by the [Google Maps API Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#11-licenses-from-you-to-google), to show custom results to the autosuggest list.
- Is it necessary to mark my custom results?
- Can a different styling be enough?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not coding.

Comment: Ok, but where to ask?
- superuser.com?
- gis.stackexchange.com?
- law.stackexchange.com?

Comment: from [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-3/info) "Ask non-programming and licensing questions in the Maps API Google Group (see full description for a link)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TL;DR - Derived from paragraph [10.3(b)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions): Different styling should be enough. Just to be sure, a lawyer
>   should be consulted.

For completeness, I answer my own question and add here a link to the Google Groups page: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/eKkRfAkcSgE/Gnsvz2ffBQAJ